# How to add more Columns when Submitting a HTML form to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to know what do I need to modify to this code, so that it will add another Column when submitted to googlesheets.

The Code along with tutorial came here --> [https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
// Original code from https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets
// Updated for 2021 and ES6 standards

const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I've been wandering in every corner of the internet, but I can't find a solution with this.

Submitting a Form to Googlesheets using HTML and Javascript and I want to know how to add more columns in the code

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `add another Column when submitted to googlesheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: The code should be run in the GoogleAppsScript, it will give you generated short-code that you can use in html form so that if you try to fill the textbox, it will generate it on googlesheets. The whole guide is in this link -> https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet

Comment: As of now, the sample code only supports generating 3 columns in googlesheets, Date, Email and Name. But I want to modify it and add more columns like Contact number, etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your showing URL, I thought that the answer to your question might be https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets#7-adding-additional-form-data . How about this?

Comment: what modifications have you tried so far?

Comment: What's keeping you from adding more columns.  Your can append more data on the the end of each row if you have it

Comment: Now... I have to ask: Why, O why, you want to use a spreadsheet as a database? An ONLINE spreadsheet at that.

Comment: Google sheets is easy and fun to use, I need to have something like a graphical presentation of data using Pivot, pie charts and I need =IMPORTRANGE function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with the code, but with the Declaration.
instead of "const" we can try to use "var"

```html
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```